# CNContactViewController Cancel Button Not Working

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use the built-in new contact UI and am getting unexpected behavior with the cancel button.  The code below works and calls up the new contact screen but the cancel button will only clear the screen entries not cancel out of the new contact screen.  In the built in contacts app hitting cancel returns to the contact list screen.  I would like the cancel button to close out the window.

```
@IBAction func newTwo(sender: AnyObject) {
    AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().requestForAccess { (accessGranted) -> Void in
        if accessGranted {
            let npvc = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: nil)
            npvc.delegate = self
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(npvc, animated: true)
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: in iOS 12 : The cancel button appeared to work "correctly", that is, tapping it throws away the data and dismisses the sheet on-screen.

in iOS 13: The cancel button appears to have "regressed", in the sense that it only dismisses an empty sheet. If you have typed anything in any field, it won't dismiss until you clear the fields. (I used quotes because I don't know the official expected-behavior)

Comment: ...and the iOS13 appears to be because the keyboard doesn't auto dismiss, which leaves it covering the action sheet with the confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

did you implement CNContactViewControllerDelegate methods?
Here's [a link to documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactViewControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html)

for example:

```
 func contactViewController(viewController: CNContactViewController, didCompleteWithContact contact: CNContact?) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It worked for me using the following code:

**Swift 3**

```
func contactViewController(_ vc: CNContactViewController, didCompleteWith con: CNContact?) {
    vc.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Also I changed the way I was calling the controller:

Instead of:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(contactViewController, animated: true)
```

the solution was:

```
self.present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: contactViewController), animated:true)
```

I found the solution using the example code [Programming-iOS-Book-Examples](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch18p713addressBookNew/ch31p973addressBook/ViewController.swift) written by [Matt Neuburg](https://github.com/mattneub):

Comment: Thanks for the Matt Neuburg's link! It helped!

Answer (score 4):

Better way to do the dismissing would be to check if the contact is nil and then dismiss it. The dismiss doesn't work if you've pushed the view controller from a navigation controller. You might have to do the following:

```
func contactViewController(viewController: CNContactViewController, didCompleteWithContact contact: CNContact?) {
  if let contactCreated =  contact
  {

  }
  else
  {
    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
  }
}
```